# How to set application wide timezone in angularjs using momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs

I have a server storing timestamps in one timezone and users living in a another timezone. I had the impression that [momentjs timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) acted as a kind of ***decorator***, and if I defined a timezone

```
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Copenhagen");
```

then subsequently usage of moment functions will use timezone defined

```
var date = moment(timestamp_from_server).calendar()
```

In my case adding one hour to all timestamps. But obviously does that not work.

Is it possible to set a "global" or app-wide timezone, so I not have to convert each and every timestamp in code, and just can rely on momentjs methods? Any suggestion, also alternatives is highly appreciated.

Note: I am using AngularJS, setting timezone in

```
app.run(function(...) {
  ...
  moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Copenhagen")
})
```

but I don't think that have any importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

If you don't want to use this module

1. You can create a factory or service for momentjs and use dependency injection to use everywhere in the application
2. Create a decorator that will set the default timezone, this will help for a consistent timezone in entire application.

Update based on comments:

If you start a new project from scratch it may be easier to use [angular moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)
othrewise the `decorator` or `app.run` or `setting in service` itself is very eassy. but when applying a timezone in an existing project make sure that the change in timezone is not affecting the existing date functions using momentjs

**A simple implementation of setting default timezone with factory**

Since factory is singleton it will be created only one

https://embed.plnkr.co/wmv11KEuJt6XJvgs5eY8/

Comment: Hey Samuel, that was a minimalistic answer :) Really appreciate it, but how, exactly? I have no problem by using momentjs in angularjs (that is why i meant angular not is important for this question at all, you emphazised angular in the edit a little bit more) but besides from providing some helpful filters I cannot see any reason for using angular moment. Why should it make any difference?

Comment: @davidkonrad In addition to useful filters and directives this module helps to have a consistent app wide timezone [configuration](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#time-zone-support). so that you can convert the server timestamp easily.

Comment: @davidkonrad i had updated the answer with respect your comment

Comment: if you only need the timezone to be applied in a factory then you can do so since service is singleton you can set timezone at that service itself. If you choose the setting for entire application you need to consider the side effects

Comment: Setting `tz.setDefault()` in `app.run()` *do* actually work app-wide, just remember to use `moment().local()` (!!) I tried out `angular-moment` but a **big** disadvantage is that the filters not can be chained, i.e `{{ date | amLocal | amCalendar }}` does not work. Also it takes over moment completely, you need to do localization / tz etc through angular-moment itself, so dropped that idea, I just change all my `moment()` references to `moment().local()`. Accepts the answer anyway, if you start a new project from scratch it *may* be easier or more intuitive to use `angular-moment` ..,

Comment: @davidkonrad i had edited my answer based on your reflections thanks